# mysql joining table on year condition

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join two tables using mysql, this is not difficult, my problem is the column I am joining on has a nonstandard type, I am joining on the birthday column which can come in a variety of different styles:

```
10/29
01/10/1984
12/32/2007
10/1997
null
1984
```

I only want to join the columns if the users are from the same year, so in the above example

```
01/10/1984
1984
```

Would be allowed for a join, while the others would be ignored.

Does mysql offer a way to split the birthdays into just their year components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could may be join using the RIGHT()function, to join on only the last 4 digits of the date, and also use INSTR() to check that the last 4 digits do not contain '/' (ie making sure it is a year).

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    tbl1 t
JOIN tbl2 ON (RIGHT(tbl1.colname, 4) = RIGHT(tbl2.colname, 4) AND INSTR(RIGHT(tbl1.colname, 4), '/') = 0)
```

This relies on the fact that the year is always the last four digits of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set @year:=1984;
Select columns from table
where concat('/',col,'/') like concat('%/',@year,'/%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `YEAR()` function.

Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return rows where user filled date field properly or enter just year.

```
select *
from table
where year(str_to_date(if(length(col_with_date) = 4, concat('01/01/', col_with_date), col_with_date , '%d/%m/%Y')) is not null
```

Please be aware of separator "/". I suppose you will need to create stored procedure to replace all possible separator to '/'. Something like the following call:

`replace_word(string_to_replace, what, with)` and the example `replace_words(col_with_date, '|/|,|.|-|', '/')`

Hope it helps